# Optaplanner project job scheduling: weekends and holidays

Tags: java, optaplanner

As I have mentioned in a previous question, I am using the excellent [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/) library to create an application which helps a custom job shop with project scheduling.  The application has the following requirement:

*"The application shall not schedule jobs on any given weekend or holiday unless a manager gives specific approval to do so."*

I am curious how I can change my domain model or scoring function to incorporate this requirement.  One basic idea is to reduce the capacity of a global renewable resource (i.e. employee) from, say, 30 days a month to 22 days a month (which accounts for weekends).  However, I can already see that this is a naive approach; if a manager wants to schedule an employee to come in one particular Saturday, increasing the employee's capacity to 23 days doesn't mean that they'll be scheduled for that Saturday.  In fact, as far as I know, since capacity is just a simple integer in our GlobalResource model, it isn't contextually aware of which specific days those are.  In my mind, the solution I'm searching for somehow doesn't define "capacity" as a integer, but rather an array of binary values where:

**capacity[*d*] = *x***, where *d* is the day of the month and *x* is the resource's availability (1 or 0).  Assuming no manager wants to schedule jobs on a given Saturday, every global renewable resource's capacity on that particular Saturday would be 0.

This probably overlaps with the Nurse Rostering problem given in the OptaPlanner examples. Or, perhaps I am approaching this problem from the entirely wrong perspective.  Any hints towards a solution to this problem are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by adding a domain class ManagerApproval to capture the extra data input which is the approval relationship between a Job and a weekend Date.

For a non-approved job from Thursday to Tuesday, the weekend days don't count towards completing the jobs.
For an approved job from Thursday to Tuesday, it's trickier, because - in theory - planner can decide to use or not use the Saturday (which will affect if the job ends on Tuesday or Monday).
So that sounds like you need an extra planning variable to capture that variance...

As for constraints, I would expect that using a weekend Date inflicts a (higher than normal) soft constraint weight.